# How to stop gradle from generating "app-metadata.properties" at compile time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

```
android_project\app\build\intermediates\app_metadata\release\app-metadata.properties
```

I'm trying to change the permissions of this file to read-only, but the compilation fails。

Nor can it be excluded by exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use this method to empty the contents of the file, if deleted it will compile and report an error

your_project app/build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
tasks.withType<PackageAndroidArtifact> {
    doFirst { appMetadata.asFile.get().writeText("") }
}
```